# Commas in SUMMARY icalendar

Tags: icalendar

Is it ok to have commas in a summary tag in a ics document?

Because I am using calcurse to load an .ics and it doesn't load the event with summary comma separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the RFC5545 Specification, Comma's need to be backslashed in that situation.  See:

**SUMMARY** is defined here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.12 as of Value Type:  **TEXT**

**TEXT** is defined here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.11

Here is part of the above specification that describes what to do with certain characters if you want to include them in a text value:

```
text       = *(TSAFE-CHAR / ":" / DQUOTE / ESCAPED-CHAR)
          ; Folded according to description above

       ESCAPED-CHAR = ("\\" / "\;" / "\," / "\N" / "\n")
          ; \\ encodes \, \N or \n encodes newline
          ; \; encodes ;, \, encodes ,

       TSAFE-CHAR = WSP / %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-39 / %x3C-5B /
                    %x5D-7E / NON-US-ASCII
          ; Any character except CONTROLs not needed by the current
          ; character set, DQUOTE, ";", ":", "\", ","

   Description:  If the property permits, multiple TEXT values are
      specified by a COMMA-separated list of values.

 ...

      The "TEXT" property values may also contain special characters
      that are used to signify delimiters, such as a COMMA character for
      lists of values or a SEMICOLON character for structured values.
      In order to support the inclusion of these special characters in
      "TEXT" property values, they MUST be escaped with a BACKSLASH
      character. ....  A COMMA character in
      a "TEXT" property value MUST be escaped with a BACKSLASH
      character.  ....
```